# Type 'MessagesController?' has no member 'setupNavBarWithUser'

Tags: swift, function, viewcontroller

Hey guys I have created my custom view controller in view controller file and I am trying to call its function from another view controller.

```
fileprivate func registeruserintoDb(_ uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)

        usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

            if err != nil {
                print(err!)
                return

            }

            //            self.messagesController?.fetchUserAndSetupNavBarTitle()
            //            self.messagesController?.navigationItem.title = values["name"] as? String
            let user = User(dictionary: values)

            MessagesController?.setupNavBarWithUser(user)

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error said, `MessagesController` is a class(type), not an object. You need to init an object first:

```
let customViewController = MessagesController()
customViewController.setupNavBarWithUser(user)
```

Comment: Thanks Luiyezheng you have saved me from a lot of frustration but i need some more help.Whenever i click create account button it gives me error like " Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17007 "The email address is already in use by another account."   @IBAction func CreateAcccountButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
 

   Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

Comment: Glad to help, if you have other problems, please consider post your problem in a new question.

Comment: i am trying to post question but site is not letting me.